# Element cropped only on mobile devices - what's going on?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I'm working on a website - http://gromocje.pl/ and I've encoutered a weird issue. I mean, the slider on homepage is cropped only on mobile devices. Everything works perfect on desktop scaled to mobile resolution.

Here's a screenshot showing the differences: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5JdN.jpg (check the title on mobile in slider)

Does anyone know what's going on? I have no idea what can be the reason but I'm sure it's something CSS related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are having

```
#owl-featured > div > div {
    margin-bottom: -45px;
}
```

In style.css line 1447,
Remove it from there and you can reduce the space between slider and content sections below

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the issue.